# Time and distance problem

Tags: problem-solving

A train starts from Jammu for Srinagar at 13:30 and reached at 17:30.Another train starts from Srinagar at 15:30 and reaches Jammu at 19:00.At what time both train will meet??.

I have solved this problem using traditional approach, but I need some tricks and short cut to do this problem,but not getting it.
Please suggest if it is possible to do any short way ,taking less time.
Not getting any proper tag.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do the trains travel at constant speed?

Comment: No it is not mentioned in d given question.I think it's not

Comment: You need constant speed for there to be a unique answer. Otherwise the train from S could wait just outside the station and meet the other train at 17:29 before rushing to J. Or the train from J could meet the train from S just outside S at 15:31 and then wait until 19:00 before going into the station.

Comment: With constant speeds, measure time in hours $t$ from 13:30. The train from J still has to cover a fraction $x=1-\frac{t}{4}$ of the distance at time $t$. The train from S has covered a fraction $x=\frac{t-2}{3.5}$ at time $t>2$. So $t=2+\frac{56}{60}$. In other words, they meet at 16:26.

Comment: Actually all you need is that at the same position, both trains go at the same speed (assuming they don't stop in between). The overall speed need not be constant.